# How to remove the entire rows if value is NULL in Azure ML studio

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am preparing the data for regression model.

[image]

I want to remove the entire row If all columns have value `NULL`.

With Clean Missing Data module seems to me like I only able to remove missing values. But `NULL` is not considers mission value.

So are there any other modules that simply can remove the entire row if all values are `NULL`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use "**Execute Python Script**" or "**Execute R Script**" to archive that. Or just use "**Apply SQL Transformation**" -> `SELECT * FROM tbl1 where column1 IS NULL AND column2 IS NULL`....

Greetings,
Stefan